# how to set ask cli set default region or aws default region

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am new to aws and alexa cli, **can any one tell how to set default region** ?
I tried using below in my mac but not able to set :

> export AWS_REGION=ap-south-1

Any help ?

Comment: run `aws configure`

Answer (score 2):

**`Just tried this and it worked:`**

In your home there is .aws folder in that just modify the credentials file :

```
cd ~.aws/
```

and nano credentials as below :

```
[ask_cli_default]

region=ap-south-1

aws_access_key_id=aws access key of user

aws_secret_access_key=aws access secret of user

[Anand_CLI_5050]
```